# Can we call a method from within a class of no instantiation

Tags: python, abstract-class, class-method

I would like to ask if there is a way to implement an interface method within a class without instantiation, or even more, if it is altogether a bad practice? If so, what will be the right way to implement a complex interface method?

Here is a prototype of my code:

```py
class calculator(abc.ABC):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def calculate(self):
        "start model"

class subcalculator(calculator):
    def calculate(self):
        return model.attr2 ** 3

    def recalculate(self):
        z = calculate(self)
        return z ** 2
```

However, this reports `calculate()` is not defined when run `subcalculator.recalculate` as it is not instantiated.

As I am just writing interface classes for my model, I suppose writing initiation is not a good idea.(Or is it?) What should I do then in such case?

**Edit:** According to @chepner 's answer, I have also figured out some hackish way to solve this problem, which I am not sure if it's right practice:

```py
    @classmethod
    def recalculate(cls, self):
        z = cls.calculate(self)
        return z ** 2
```

Also it's worth mentioning the object/model part of the structure:

```py
#In model.py

class model(object):
    def __init__(self, attr1):
        self.attr1 = attr1

class submodel(model):
    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2):
        super().__init__(attr1)
        self.attr2 = attr2
```

So my hope is to write `calculator` as an interface class which can interact with `model` etc.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://pythonbasics.org/classmethod/ ?

Comment: Ah ok, a common practice in this case is to raise a `NotImplementedError' from the abstract function, then reimplement the method it in the subclasses.

Comment: The error isn't due to lack of instantiation; it's due to the fact that there is no global function named `calculate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`calculate` is a method whether or not you ever create an instance, and has to be referred to as such.

```
class subcalculator(calculator):
    def calculate(self):
        return model.attr2 ** 3

    def recalculate(self):
        z = subcalculator.calculate(self)
        return z ** 2
```

Of course, it's better to let the inheritance model determine exactly which `calculate` method needs to be called:

```
def recalculate(self):
    z = self.calculate()
    return z ** 2
```

Comment: I suppose when it comes to interface the second option cannot be implemented? As I mentioned the `calculator` class is just interface class for `model` class. In such case if I use `subcalculator.recalculate(a_model)` it will raise an error as `a_model` object has no attribute `calculate`. Is there anyway to handle it without hard-quoting the class name? Or is it something pertaining to design pattern?

Comment: What is `a_model`? If it's not an instance of `subcalculator`, then it shouldn't be passed as the first instance of the (instance) method `recalculate`. You may want a static method instead, or just make `recalculate` an ordinary function.

Comment: Sorry for not making things clear. My goal was to mimic some baby strategy pattern described [here](https://medium.com/@sheikhsajid/design-patterns-in-python-part-1-the-strategy-pattern-54b24897233e). The difference is he did only one method for each, and without any cross-method reference.

Comment: Also I have found some way to solve the problem without hard-referring the class name. Would you mind check out if it is the right practice?

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean by "interface class"; I *suspect* you are trying to port some sort of Java/C++ pattern that simply isn't necessary in Python. Also, I suggested a *static* method, not a *class* method.